# Group rows with the same value only if they are one after the other in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I want to achieve something very similar to this but using MySQL:

[Group rows if certain column value directly after another in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8255478/group-rows-if-certain-column-value-directly-after-another-in-sql?answertab=active#tab-top)

However, in my case the id is not incremented by 1 but there is a random gap so for instance:

```
0 -- bob -- note -- 14:00
3 -- bob -- note -- 15:00
9 -- bob -- time -- 15:00
20 - bob -- note -- 15:00

I need to display:
0 -- bob -- note -- 14:00
9 -- bob -- time -- 15:00
20 - bob -- note -- 15:00
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: What is the logic behind omitting `3 -- bob -- note -- 15:00` ?

Comment: I'm not ommitting, I simply want to group them into one record if they come after each other.

Comment: No, you're omitting. You appear to be keeping the one with the lowest "column 1" value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select id,  Name,  Event,  Time 
  from (select *, @e prev, @e:=Event 
          from table, (select @e:='') e) t 
  where prev<>Event
```

[Demo on sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cc3a0/1)

Comment: would prefer to see explicit use of `CROSS JOIN`, and shouldn't initializing @e use single quotes? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cc3a0/2

Comment: @Used_By_Already OK about quotes. Could you say in two words difference of using cross join here?

Comment: @splash58 Great thanks both of these are working! 
Could you kindly explain this part of the query please: select *, @e prev, @e:=Event from table, (select @e:='') e as the syntax is new to me. What I have concluded is that (select @e:='') is for initialising variable e but how does it know it should get the previous record by @e prev is that an sql keyword?

Comment: @sc1234 `@e prev` creates field with previous value, `@e:=Event` change `e`  variable with current Event for next step